# How do you make lists not reset in a while loop?

Tags: python

I want to add values to a list but not make it reset every time it loops back to the beginning.

```
def number():
    print "Input a number to add to a list. When done press q"
    loop = 0
    while loop == 0:
        loop = 1
        totallist = []
        x = raw_input()
        if x == 'q':
            print "Your total is:"
            return totallist
        else:
            totallist.append(number)
            loop = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

move `totallist = []` out of the loop

Answer (score 2):

```
def number():
    print "Input a number to add to a list. When done press q"
    loop = 0
    totallist = [] # <-- Move it here
    while loop == 0:
        loop = 1
        # totallist = []
        x = raw_input()
        if x == 'q':
            print "Your total is:"
            return totallist
        else:
            totallist.append(number)
            loop = 0
```